# Is there a way to get the user location not by IP

Tags: location, ip

i have seen some pages that display your current location very accurately and dont seem to be doing it thorough your IP since i tried by using a proxy from another country and they still display my actual location. Is there anyway to get the user location other than by the IP? and if so, is it possible to bypass that so webmasters dont see my actual location?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Geolocation

http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Sample page: http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: That is definitely using the user IP because it detects my proxy location and not my actual location.

Answer (score 0):

proxies of this type are supposed to deliver a web experience where that you're location is not shared with anyone but in some cases the actual online proxy- who wouldn't ever use this data.  All I can recommend, is a site called hidemyass(dot).com

I found that it tends to use IP address based in the United Kingdom, but that could be based on your own geographical location.

Comment: The problem is that some sites only show their content only if you are in certain country, so i always used to disguise my IP with that countrys IP in order to fool their system into allow me to see the content but its not working anymore.